# Reactjs Preflight Request Err

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, security, cors

I am trying to `fetch` an API on `ReactJS` with **basic authentication** (this is a complex request).

I have stumbled upon many articles, most are suggesting to modify something on the `node` but here, in this case, I am not using any node server. I have commented out all the `NodeJS` code and I am fetching this API directly from `componentDidMount()`, apparently, `ReactJS` has it's own backend server. I am using a third party cors chrome plugin for the time being, but I am averse towards using third party proxy servers like `Heroku` or `NGINX` or third party libs like `axios`. Cors chrome plugin helped me to resolve the `access-control-allow-origin` issue but it then raised this new issue.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://server-iam-fetching/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I tried few things like appending access control checks on the header but none seems to work. Here is my sample code:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*")

headers.append('Authorization','Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    credentials
    allow requests
    allow origins
    ..
    ..
    etc
const someRequest = new Request(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers:headers,
  mode:'cors',
  cache: 'default'
});

componentDidMount(){
  fetch(someRequest)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
}
```

Feel free to comment for any questions. I am on MacOS. Also, I don't want to disable my chrome web security.

Comment: @AmerllicA I am on MacOS

Comment: Do you have this issue just on development mode? and the production mode and run on launch is there the CORS error?

Comment: Yes, I am on dev mode and I am seeing this issue once I launch it.

Comment: I will post an answer just for development but it is not the final answer. if it is useful just the answer.

Comment: Remove `headers.append("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*")`. That one it’s own won’t make things work, but it’s wrong and it’s not helping. You can’t set that header manually in your JavaScript code. The browser controls that header.

Comment: If you have admin access to the `https://server-iam-fetching/`, then you need to configure that server to respond to unauthenticated OPTIONS requests with a 200 OK. Right now, it’s responding with some error code — maybe a 401 error, if it’s expecting to find that Authorization request header in the request. But it won’t find any Authorization header in the preflight OPTIONS request, because per the CORS protocol requirements, browsers don’t send any credentials in the preflight OPTIONS request. So you can’t have the server configured to require authentication for OPTIONS requests to any route

Comment: @sideshowbarker unfortunately, I am not an admin, any other suggestions?

Comment: If you don’t control the `https://server-iam-fetching/` server and it’s not responding to the preflight request with a 200 OK, then there are no suggestions anybody can give you here that would actually work — that is, as long as your requirement is to make it work from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser. Your only alternative is to instead make the request from your backend code on the `http://localhost:3000` backend, and consume the response from your backend code on the `http://localhost:3000` backend. You do in fact have a backend web server running there which you can configure

Comment: @sideshowbarker yeah, I agree, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you have access to the API you should fix it on your NGINX configuration or on backend codes. but if you have no access there are two recommended way:

1. Write a mapper proxy API by node/express and send all of your calls to it and the mapper API send it to the main API. in the mapper you have access allow all origins:

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const request = require('request');

   const app = express();

   app.use((req, res, next) => {
       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
       next();
   });

   app.get('/jokes/random', (req, res) => {
       request(
           { url: 'https://the-main-api-address' },
           (error, response, body) => {
               if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
                   return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
               }

               res.json(JSON.parse(body));
           }
       )
   });

   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
   app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));
   ```
2. If you are using `webpack-dev-server` you can use below config to allow all origins on your webpack devServer:

   ```
   devServer: {
     ...
     headers: {
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
     }
   }
   ```

   Or pass a `proxy`:

   ```
       devServer: {
      contentBase: DIST_FOLDER,
      port: 8888,
      // Send API requests on localhost to API server get around CORS.
      proxy: {
         '/api': {
            target: {
               host: "0.0.0.0",
               protocol: 'http:',
               port: 8080
            },
            pathRewrite: {
               '^/api': ''
            }
         }
      }
   },
   ```

**Hint:** I prefer to use the first one.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not using any `express()` or `nginx` in my code, it's just pure `reactjs` invoking fetch from `componentDidMount()`

Comment: @JumpMan, so pick the second way, use webpack config to settle CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

This post is just for your **development** mode, you can launch an instance of Google Chrome that has not security modules and it won't send `OPTION` calls and definitely you won't see CORS error, so open your terminal and write the following commands in it:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't update this in question, this won't help me.

Comment: @JumpMan, I will post another answer to your whole project. both development and production.

Comment: @JumpMan, it is a solution for some projects like my projects that has CORS error just on the development area and on the production CORS will disappear. so if it is possible to remove the newly updated sentence on your question post.